# Using the same font with different sizes in libgdx

Tags: libgdx, fonts

I am using BitmapFonts, LabelStyles and Labels for my texts.

I want to resize some labels, so i use this.

```
fontType.scale(-.6f);

LabelStyle style = new LabelStyle(fontType, Color.WHITE);

titleLabel = new Label("Points", style);
titleLabel.setColor(Color.RED);
titleLabel.x = 260; 
titleLabel.y = 310;
```

but when i want to resize another label, all the labels containing that font resize (I create a new LabelStyle). So i resize the label instead of the font, but that doesnt solve the problem, because it doesnt resize the label, any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would preffer adding this as a comment, but i have no commetn priviledge yet.

Have you tried creating a new bitmapfont instead of a new label?

Comment: Yes, but is it correct doing that if its the same font? :/

Comment: I assume it's not that big of a deal. Can't check libgdx code at work. But isn't a spritebatch passed as parameter for the draw method? That at least lets you know it wont impact too much on performance i guess

Comment: I have tried that and the load time increases a lot XD (4 seconds with 4 bitmapfonts built in the constructor) u.u